# Expected number of cards between first Jack and first queen given first Jack appears before first Queen.

Tags: probability, expected-value, conditional-expectation, card-games

> Suppose we draw cards from a standard deck one-by-one. Find the
> expected number of cards after the first Jack and before the first
> Queen given that the first Jack appears before the first Queen.

My approach is that we label all 4 Jacks and 4 Queens in the deck as special cards. Now there are 44 other cards in the deck to be inserted in 9 places. Therefore on average there are $\frac{44}{9}$ cards between two consecutive special cards.

Given that first Jack comes before first Queen, there are $\frac{8!}{2}$ ways that can happen in special cards. Now, let $P_k$ be the probability that first Queen is the kth card after first Jack in our special cards. Therefore the total expected number of cards between first Jack and first Queen is $$\frac{44}{9}(P_1 \cdot 1 + P_2 \cdot 2 + P_3 \cdot 3 + P_4 \cdot 4) = \frac{352}{45}$$ but I know that the actual answer is $\frac{379}{45}$. What is the problem in my approach?

Comment: Well,  if the the second jack precedes the first queen,  then you have to count that jack as it is between the two.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is that you have counted the expected length of gaps between Jacks and Queens or between Jacks and Jacks with $\frac{52-8}{9}$ for each such gap, but have not counted those Jacks which come after the first Jack and before the first Queen. Try $$P_1\cdot\left(0+\frac{44}9 \cdot 1\right) + P_2\cdot\left(1+\frac{44}9 \cdot 2\right) + P_3\cdot\left(2+\frac{44}9 \cdot 3\right) + P_4\cdot\left(3+\frac{44}9 \cdot 4\right)$$  to get $\frac{379}{45}$.

Comment: Very stupid of me, thanks a lot!